# Switch text of span element based on whether the div is expanded or collapsed

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to have three divs , initially all are closed.When the div is closed a span to right side is shown which is an arrow pointing towards right , when I click any div I want that the corresponding span arrow points down and again when that div is collapsed it should point right.Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzR6h/).I think I am missing something , can anyone just help me out with this.
Also if any one could just let know better ways of doing this task (entire collapse , expansion) , it would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You may take a look at JQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/. For your problem you never set back the right arrow character on collapsed div

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue ya I think that might help ,that is a better way of doing it.

Comment: @freebird the demo from RoryMcCrossan that you've aceepted his answer not working ; i have tested it on IE and FF and the first and middle divs expands ** but when clicking on it again it collapse then expand at the same time !! ** can i say you shouldnt accept his answer because his demo not working its up to you but hoping to benefit other people who would face the same problem the answer must be accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few amends to your code, including using classes to group elements. Your code was originally set the selected arrow, so you needed to change all the divs back their default state before completing the actions on the clicked one.

Try this:

```
$('.main').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);

    if (!$el.next(".sub").is(":visible")) {   
        // reset all
        $('.sub').slideUp("slow");
        $('.arrow').html("&#9654;");

        // set current
        $el.next('.sub').slideDown("slow");
        $('.arrow', $el).html("&#9660;");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
</div>
<div class="sub">
    <p>Here there are many images</p>
    <p>Here there are many images</p>
    <p>Here there are many images</p>
    <p>Here there are many images</p>
    <p>Here there are many images</p>
    <p>Here there are many images</p>
</div>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/SzR6h/29/)

Comment: that was great just about perfect , thanks for the help.much appreciated.

Comment: @RoyMcCrossan hi your demo not working well it expands but not collapse correctyl ** means once it collapse it expands again  ** need edit

Answer (score 1):

You are using slideToggle() which toggles the appearance but you are only assigning $('#sp2').html("▼");  per click which means whenever the div will be clicked, the span will get this value. You will have to place a check to see if a div is being expanded or collapsed and use appropriate code to set the span.
HTML
    ▶
jQuery

```
$('#one').click(function() {
        $('.sub1').slideToggle("slow");
        if ($("#sp1").hasClass("expand")) {
            $('#sp1').html("&#9660;").removeClass("expand");
        }
        else {
            $('#sp1').html("&#9654;").addClass("expand");
        }

        $('.sub2').slideUp("slow");
        $('.sub3').slideUp("slow");


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

HERE is a **DEMO**

i used it in a project tested :)

but **note** you just have to **add** the images down and left **URL** directory on you machine

[jsfiddle demo menu dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/2LucD/)

i used this `JQuery` code 
and some `CSS` and of course `HTML`

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //slides the element with class "menu_head" when paragraph with class "menu_head" is clicked
        $("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function()
        {
            $(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(images/menu/down.png)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(images/menu/left.png)"});
        });

    });
```

Comment: @freebird welcome glad it helpt but be sure to add the arrows left and down to you directory on i.e  `root/images/menu/down.png`

Comment: ya I know it was a bit problematic , could you just drop him the message as well.thanks